# Xeon processor vs Core I7 for games and blender?

Tags: cpu, performance

I use blender a lot and I would like to play some games like GTA V, Watch dogs, ...etc.

In my opinion, more cores and cache memory means more CPU power so I tend to buy a Xeon processor but I've never tried it. I think any Xeon processor with 8 cores is better than any CI7 win 4 cores if they have the same GHz, same cache and both have hyper threading. In Egypt, for a given price of used processors, Xeon processors tend to have more cores or more cache than core i7 ones.

Some opinions also agree that they are better for animation and rendering in blender.

When it comes to games, many people say that Core I7 is better. They say that 4 fast cores are better than 8 or even 12 slow cores but I don't get that. I would like to know what I'm missing from a technical point of view. Are Xeon processors too bad for games like GTA V, watch dogs and Fifa or pes?

I understand that the whole system affects the performance (like RAM and graphics card) but I'll assume that the system is the almost same in both processors.

Comment: Hardware recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: @spikey_richie It's actually a question in disguise: _"They say that 4 fast cores are better than 8 or even 12 slow cores but I don't get that."_

Comment: A similar question was asked just a few hours ago and has a good answer: https://superuser.com/q/1552756/194694

Answer (score 2):

It takes one woman nine months to make one baby, but it doesn't mean that nine women can make a baby in one month.

Computer programs don't scale perfectly over CPU cores. Doubling number of cores won't necessarily double the performance in specific task.

Some algorithms, such as those used by 3D modelling software for example, parallelize very well. Others - like making babies - don't scale at all.

Programs that do lots of different kinds of stuff at once, such as games, are especially hard to optimize for multiple cores. To max out all cores the program would have to divide its work evenly. But estimating how much time something will take is oftentimes hard to impossible in mixed workloads.

You also have to consider that not all cores are made equal and there's more to performance than just frequency, cache and other numbers. This misconception is called the [megahertz myth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megahertz_myth). Combine this with mixed workload and efficient work distribution becomes very complicated.

Computer games aren't designed to scale to infinite number of cores because average consumer-grade CPU has only 4 or 6 of them. So they are built to work well on just  a few of them. Some (older) games are even hard-limited to run on 1 or 2 cores because the game engine breaks when more is available. That's why usually faster cores are better than more cores for gaming.

Comment: hahha thank you for this answer :) I got your point but I feel like I would still buy Xeon if it has the same price with core I7. Extra unused cores will not harm but less cores than what the programs require will slow down. Plus, Xeon usually has more cache. I still don't see why should I buy Core I7? Does I7 have significantly faster cores?

Comment: You should probably look at some benchmarks to estimate what kind of performance you should expect. There will be power consumption and heat dissipation difference too, if you want to save on electricity or have a quieter PC the i7 may be a better choice.